# Magento 1.9 - cannot login to admin after renamed Document Root

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, document-root

I have a subdomain say dev.domain.com that points to document root `public_html/dev`.

Worked fine, but for good reasons I renamed the folder `dev` to `devm19`, also modified the subdomain to point to `public_html/devm19`.

Problem is I can't login to the admin - The form for UN and PW is there, credentials are correct, but the form key in URL bar keeps refreshing, you just can't get inside to admin.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

See the result of the below SQL

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%web/cookie/cookie_domain%';
```

If it gives you "dev.domain.com" in the value field, then either make it blank or give "devm19.domain.com" as value.

Then flush the cache, open the admin panel in private window and you will be able to login.

Comment: It was null - I updated the value with dev.domain.com, didn't help.  Tried making it null again, no luck. Can't login still.

Comment: you need to add the new domain there. if it didnt work, then try to see the permission of your session save path.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind clarifying what to look for in permissions of session save path?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by modifying app/etc/local.xml.

Added/replaced records for:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[/tmp/session]]></session_save_path>
```